# How to specify X values between a certain time where X is a different variable to time?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot ACI on the Y axis and % moonlight illumination between -105 and 120 mins since sunset on the X axis

I want to separate the data I have for % moonlight illumination into:

sunset data: -105 to 120 mins since sunset

true night data: 120 min since sunset to 120 min before sunrise

sunrise data: 120 min before sunrise to 120 min after sunrise

but I don't know how to do this!

I can plot this and it looks like this

```
ggplot(data = data.thesis, mapping = 
         aes(x=minsincesunset, y=aci,
             colour=rank_light)) + geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-105,120)) + geom_smooth(se=F)
```

[image: my plot]

but I essentially want

```
ggplot(data = data.thesis, mapping = 
         aes(x=moonlight_fraction, y=aci,
             colour=rank_light)) + geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-105,120)) + geom_smooth(se=F)
```

whereby the limits are the mins since sunset, so I have moonlight fraction as the x-axis, but between certain mins since sunset

I would do this three times with different limits to separate between sunset, true night and sunrise data

Edits for clarification (first post hehe):

Moonlight_fraction is the percentage of moonlight showing e.g. the moon cycle in a fraction
All variables that I want to use for the plots are continuous numerical data from my dataset

Below is a partial screenshot of my dataset just in case it helps visualisation

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJQ3W.png)

I would like the output to look like this (I would use ggarrange to combine them into one plot)

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms7xZ.jpg)

Or, basically like this, which was created in JMP, which I want to recreate in R

[Plot created in JMP that I would like to recreate in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dokQn.png)

Comment: What is moonlight_fraction? Is it a column in your data frame? What type of data is it? Discrete? Numeric?. Although we can infer some of the data structure from the plot you have included, you haven't really supplied us with enough information to answer your question. Your description of the expected output is also unclear. Could you please include some reproducible data and a sketch of the desired output? Thanks.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: @AllanCameron have edited the post- thank you kindly, first post so wasn't sure how much detail to put!!

Answer (score 0):

ok, ok, I got help.

```
sunset<-subset(data.thesis, time.period=='sunset')

truenight<-subset(data.thesis, time.period=='nighttime')

sunrise<-subset(data.thesis, time.period=='sunrise')
```

just defined subsets and then was able to plot as normal then... :-)